# How do you define matrices with some gekko parameters and some zeros in gekko?

Tags: arrays, gekko

I am trying to implement a problem with gekko where I have some matrices where I would like some elements to be set to parameters, while the other elements are zeros.

Here is an example of my thought process:

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO()
q0 = m.Array(m.Param, 1*3, value=0) # Some initial value
q0[1].value = 1.
G = np.zeros((2, 2*3))  # Example of matrix 
G[0, :3] = q0           # Desired look: G = np.array([[q0[0], q0[1], q0[2], 0, 0, 0], 
                        #                             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

But this gives the ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I notice that it is possible to define it as stated in my "Desired look", but when the dimensions increase this seems impractical.

Another thing that works as I've seen is defining the G by `G = m.Array(m.Param, (2, 2*3), value=0)`, then I do not get an error. However, every single element in G becomes a parameter, even the zeros. And this seems unnecessary? Or will it not be a problem, even when the size of G becomes 10x30?
The following code snippet shows the example

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO()
q0 = m.Array(m.Param, 1*3, value=0) # Some initial value
q0[1].value = 1.
G = m.Array(m.Param, (2, 2*3), value=0)
G[0, :3] = q0
y1 = m.Array(m.Param, 2*1*3)
G@y1
```

Out[3]:
array([(((((((p1)*(p16))+((p2)*(p17)))+((p3)*(p18)))+((p7)*(p19)))+((p8)*(p20)))+((p9)*(p21))),
(((((((p10)*(p16))+((p11)*(p17)))+((p12)*(p18)))+((p13)*(p19)))+((p14)*(p20)))+((p15)*(p21)))],
dtype=object)

Answer (score 1):

Define a numpy array as an object type.

```py
G = np.zeros((2,2*3)).astype(object)
```

The Gekko parameters can then be used to redefine elements of the `G` matrix. Here is a complete example:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO()
G = np.zeros((2,2*3)).astype(object)

q0 = m.Array(m.Param, 1*3, value=0) # Some initial value
q0[1].value = 1.
G[0,:3] = q0

print(G)
```

Symbolic matrix operations can now be performed on this hybrid matrix of constants and Gekko objects. It generally isn't a problem to have 300 gekko parameters as long as it isn't a dynamic problem where you multiply by a long number of time steps.